# Django rest blog: Customized uploading

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am learning django rest framework, and started by building a basic django-blog application from it. NOw  I want my blogs to be customized easily like giving options like

1. Adding links to the blog
2. Adding multiple images to blog(At different position)
3. Adding sub-headings in blog

I have looked up for it but can not find what is exactly the thing I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a lot of research I found the solution to my problem.
TinyMCE provides all these functionalities and its also easy to integrate with django